# Vários Framworks dentro de um domínio separado em pastas

Tags: php, htaccess, framework

Tenho um framework, onde quero dividi-lo em vários frameworks (MVC) por pasta na raiz do domínio. Na raiz do domínio não possuo arquivo algum, existem pastas onde possuo arquivo na raiz de cada pasta um `.htaccess` assim:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1
```

Gostaria de que no meu www.meudominio.com.br tivesse diversas pastas, exemplo:

> www.meudominio.com.br/pasta1
>   www.meudominio.com.br/pasta2
>   www.meudominio.com.br/pasta3

E, em cada pastas (ex.: pasta1, pasta2, pasta3) tivesse um arquivo `.htaccess` para carregar um framework separadamente com demais estrutura de arquivos com o arquivo em conjunto de inicialização `index.php` e demais estrutura de pasta (framework)

> - app
>     -- controllers
>     -- models
>     -- views
> - system
>     -- helpers
> - web
>
> .htaccess
>   index.php

Comment: Ok, mas qual é o problema? Criar as pastas com os `.htaccess` dentro não funcionou?

Comment: Criei sim separadamente, mas, dá erro de redirecionamento dos locais, por exemplo, some o caminho da pasta1 por exemplo. Eu entro com www.meudominio.com.br/pasta1/admin/login (onde admin é o controller e login a action) após isso tudo que é feito é desaparecido do caminho absoluto o caminho raiz "pasta1".

Comment: Como assim desaparecido? Tem como você [edit] a pergunta e adicionar o conteúdo desses arquivos `.htaccess`? Existe um `.htaccess` na raiz do projeto?

Comment: Eu utilizo um www.dominio.com.br/controller/action, onde www.dominio.com.br é o caminho base absoluto sempre, como fazer com que seja o caminho base absoluto um nível de pasta por exemplo, achei que pudesse ser definido em algum lugar uma única vez, do contrário até caminhos de imagens terei que definir tal pasta.

Comment: Mas se você quer múltiplos frameworks, o caminho base não deveria ser `dominio.com/pasta1`? Se não, como sua aplicação saberá qual framework ele deverá carregar?

Comment: Verdade, mas é isso que não estou sabendo fazer e precisando desta ajuda. Onde definir o caminho base das URL's amigáveis?

Comment: Está um pouco difícil de entender. Se você acessa `dominio.com/pasta1/controller/action`, irá executar o `.htaccess` do diretório `pasta1` e carregará a página `pasta1/index.php?url=controler/action`, certo? A `action` acessada é exibida? O que acontece exatamente quando acessado essa URL?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61437/discussion-between-thyago-thysoft-and-anderson-carlos-woss).